# I cannot retrieve all entries from openLDAP database

Tags: openldap

I set up openLDAP on my Ubuntu server and filled the database via `python-ldap` with 10.000 persons.

Now, when trying to search for all of them, at first I only got 500 entries.

`$ ldapsearch -x -h 192.168.1.222 -b dc=ldap-test,dc=xxx,dc=xx`

I googled for a solution, and I read about a server side limit.

Then I changed following value from 500 to:

```
olcSizeLimit: unlimited
```

I also tried 15.000, but with the same effect.

Now, with the same search command I get:

```
# numResponses: 992
# numEntries: 991
```

I cannot find any 992 or 991 number restriction anywhere. I also grepped for `sizelimit` - only result is the above setting.

I also read about client side restrictions, but I tried the same search command against the old, deprecated test server, and there I get all 10.000 results.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the generation of the data.

I used the Python package `Faker` which faked the last names, which I used as `cn`.

As `Faker` only provides a limited number of last names, the generation of names errored silently.

I fixed the problem by using the complete name for `cn`.